# $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$ is differentiable iff all coordinate functions $f_i:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ are differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

What I tried:

Since $f$ is differentiable, there is a linear function $L$ such that 
$$f(x)=f(a)+L(x-a)+(\text{remainder})$$
 Let $f_i$ be a coordinate function. Is it true that $\pi_1\circ L:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ is a linear function such that $$f_i(x)=f(a)+(\pi_i\circ L)(x-a)+(\text{remainder})? $$ For the converse:

For every coordinate function $f_i$ there is a linear function $L_i:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$. We need to compose a linear $F:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$. Define $F$ as $(x-a)\mapsto (L_1(x-a),...,L_m(x-a))$. **Is this linear? Do these make sense?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just saying that you know an $m\times n$ matrix iff you know all its rows. What you have is correct.

Of course, to be complete, we need to include discussion of the remainder/error (which I'll call $\epsilon$). If each coordinate $f_i$ is differentiable, given $\varepsilon>0$, we know there is $\delta_i$ so that $\|x-a\|<\delta_i \implies |\epsilon_i|<\varepsilon/\sqrt m$, so $\|x-a\|<\delta=\min(\delta_1,\dots,\delta_m) \implies \|\epsilon\|=\|(\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_m)\|<\varepsilon$. Conversely if $f$ is differentiable, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta$ so that $\|x-a\|<\delta\implies \|\epsilon\|<\varepsilon \implies |\epsilon_i|\le \|\epsilon\|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Nice way to think about it, thank you.

Comment: Well, "differentiable" is more than the existence of all partial derivatives.  So I think this paraphrase is sometimes not good.

Comment: @GEdgar, you're absolutely right. I've edited.

Answer (score 3):

There is a trivial yet fundamental fact about Euclidean spaces.

> The projection $\pi_j:$ $(x_1, x_2,\cdots, x_m)\in\mathbb{R}^{m}\mapsto x_j\in\mathbb{R}$ is linear and smooth.

I am sure you can prove this fact. After you have done it, note that $f_j=\pi_j\circ f$.  Then chain rule gives what you need.